# How do I append to an observable inside the observable itself

Tags: rxjs, reactivex

My situation is as follows: I am performing sequential HTTP requests, where one HTTP request depends on the response of the previous. I would like to combine the response data of all these HTTP requests into one observable. I have implemented this before using an async generator. The code for this was relatively simple:

```js
async function* AsyncGeneratorVersion() {
  let moreItems = true; // whether there is a next page
  let lastAssetId: string | undefined = undefined; // used for pagination
  while (moreItems) {
    // fetch current batch (this performs the HTTP request)
    const batch = await this.getBatch(/* arguments */, lastAssetId);
    moreItems = batch.more_items;
    lastAssetId = batch.last_assetid;
    yield* batch.getSteamItemsWithDescription();
  }
}
```

I am trying to move away from async generators, and towards RxJs Observables. My best (and working) attempt is as follows:

```js
const observerVersion = new Observable<SteamItem>((subscriber) => {
  (async () => {
    let moreItems = true;
    let lastAssetId: string | undefined = undefined;
    while (moreItems) {
      // fetch current batch (this performs the HTTP request)
      const batch = await this.getBatch(/* arguments */, lastAssetId);
      moreItems = batch.more_items;
      lastAssetId = batch.last_assetid;
      const items = batch.getSteamItemsWithDescription();
      for (const item of items) subscriber.next(item);
    }
    subscriber.complete();
  })();
});
```

Now, I believe that there must be some way of improving this Observer variant - this code does not seem very reactive to me. I have tried several things using `pipe`, however unfortunately these were all unsuccessful.
I found `concatMap` to come close to a solution. This allowed me to concat the next HTTP request as an observable (done with the `this.getBatch` method), however I could not find a good way to also not abandon the response of the current HTTP request.

How can this be achieved? In short I believe this problem could be described as appending data to an observable inside the observable itself. (But perhaps this is not a good way of handling this situation)

Answer (score 2):

### TLDR;

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-njtwpr?devtoolsheight=60)'s a working StackBlitz demo.

---

### Explanation

Here would be my approach:

```js
// Faking an actual request
const makeReq = (prevArg, response) =>
  new Promise((r) => {
    console.log(`Running promise with the prev arg as: ${prevArg}!`);
    setTimeout(r, 1000, { prevArg, response });
  });

// Preparing the sequential requests.
const args = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

from(args)
  .pipe(
    // Running the reuqests sequantially.
    mergeScan(
      (acc, crtVal) => {
        // `acc?.response` will refer to the previous response
        // and we're using it for the next request.
        return makeReq(acc?.response, crtVal);
      },
      // The seed(works the same as `reduce`).
      null,
      // Making sure that only one request is run at a time.
      1
    ),

    // Combining all the responses into one object
    // and emitting it after all the requests are done.
    reduce((acc, val, idx) => ({ ...acc, [`request${idx + 1}`]: val }), {})
  )
  .subscribe(console.warn);
```

Firstly, `from(array)` will emit each item from the array, synchronously and one by one.

Then, there is `mergeScan`. It is exactly the result of combining `scan` and `merge`. With `scan`, we can accumulate values(in this case we're using it to have access to the response of the previous request) and what `merge` does is to allow us to use `observables`.
To make things a bit easier to understand, think of the `Array.prototype.reduce` function. It looks something like this:

```js
[].reduce((acc, value) => { return { ...acc }}, /* Seed value */{});
```

What `merge` does in `mergeScan` is to allow us to use **the accumulator** something like `(acc, value) => new Observable(...)` instead of `return { ...acc }`. The latter indicates a synchronous behavior, whereas with the former we can have asynchronous behavior.

Let's go a bit step by step:

- when `1` is emitted, `makeReq(undefined, 1)` will be invoked
- after the first `makeReq`(from above) resolves, `makeReq(1, 2)` will be invoked
- after `makeReq(1, 2)` resolves, `makeReq(2, 3)` will be invoked and so on...

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This approach makes a lot of sense to me. I have posted a different solution which I consider perhaps a bit more elegant. It uses expand instead of mergeScan to achieve pretty much the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Somebody I consulted regarding this matter came up with this solution, I think it's quite elegant:

```js
defer(() => this.getBatch(options)).pipe(
  expand(({ more_items, last_assetid }) =>
    more_items
      ? this.getBatch({ ...options, startAssetId: last_assetid })
      : EMPTY,
  ),
  concatMap((batch) => batch.getSteamItemsWithDescription()),
);
```

From my understanding the use of `expand` here is very similar to the use of `mergeScan` in @Andrei's answer